# Transform to nest items within one list when source contains flat tagging

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML file:

```
<li id="s9781452281988.n39.i34"><i>See also</i>
<a class="term-ref" id="s9781452281988.n39.i6525" href="#s9781452281988.n39.i1899">Emotion</a>;
    <a class="term-ref" id="s9781452281988.n39.i6526" href="#s9781452281988.n39.i3312">Interpersonal conflict</a></li>
```

And I want the output to be the following:

```
<item>See also
 <list rend="runon">
     <item><term>Emotion</term></item>
     <item><term>Interpersonal conflict</term></item>
 </list>
</item>
```

Basically if I have multiple a[@class='term-ref'], the first instance should start the **list rend="runon"** and subsequent a[@class='term-ref'] should be included as **item/term** within the list.

The below was my try, but it is not working as I had hoped, and is closing the **list** before the second **item/term** (elements which are also not being output):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:element name="item">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@class='term-ref'][1]">
    <xsl:element name="list">
        <xsl:attribute name="rend" select="'runon'"/>
        <xsl:element name="item">
            <xsl:element name="term">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="a[@class='term-ref'][position() >1]">
            <xsl:element name="item">
                <xsl:element name="term">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li//text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '.,;', '')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the source, XML, the above stylesheet produces this output:

```
<item>See also
<list rend="runon">
    <item><term>Emotion</term></item>
</list>
    Interpersonal conflict</item>
```

Which is incorrect.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your wanted result starts with `<item>` but ends with `</list>`, that way it is not a well-formed snippet of XML. That way it is difficult to tell what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This short transformation (almost completely "push style", with no conditional instructions, no `xsl:element` and no unnecessary function calls like `translate()` or `replace()`):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="li">
  <item><xsl:apply-templates/></item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a[@class='term-ref'][1]">
     <list rend="runon">
         <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
              select="../a[@class='term-ref']"/>
     </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a[@class='term-ref']" mode="group">
    <item><term><xsl:apply-templates/></term></item>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="a[@class='term-ref']|li/text()" priority="-1"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document -- which *is* well-formed:**

```
<li id="s9781452281988.n39.i34"><i>See also</i>
  <a class="term-ref" id="s9781452281988.n39.i6525"
     href="#s9781452281988.n39.i1899">Emotion</a>;
  <a class="term-ref" id="s9781452281988.n39.i6526"
     href="#s9781452281988.n39.i3312">Interpersonal conflict.</a>.
</li>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<item>See also<list rend="runon">
      <item>
         <term>Emotion</term>
      </item>
      <item>
         <term>Interpersonal conflict.</term>
      </item>
   </list>
</item>
```

Comment: This worked out great for me. I haven't tried out using "mode"s yet, but this was a great way to start.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

**XML Input** (well-formed)

```
<doc>
    <li id="s9781452281988.n39.i34"><i>See also</i>
        <a class="term-ref" id="s9781452281988.n39.i6525" href="#s9781452281988.n39.i1899">Emotion</a>;
        <a class="term-ref" id="s9781452281988.n39.i6526" href="#s9781452281988.n39.i3312">Interpersonal conflict.</a>.
    </li>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="i/text()"/>
            <xsl:if test="a">
                <list rend="runon">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>                   
                </list>
            </xsl:if>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <item><term><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></term></item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'[.,;]','')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <item>See also<list rend="runon">
         <item>
            <term>Emotion</term>
         </item>
         <item>
            <term>Interpersonal conflict</term>
         </item>
      </list>
   </item>
</doc>
```

Comment: This works for my sample but isn't exactly what I wanted. But thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:element name="item">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="items" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li//text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '.,;', ''))"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="a[@class = 'term-ref']" />

  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="items" />
  <xsl:template match="li" mode="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="items" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="li[count(a[@class = 'term-ref']) > 1]" mode="items">
    <list rend="runon">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="a[@class = 'term-ref']" mode="items" />
    </list>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a[@class = 'term-ref']" mode="items">
    <item>
      <term>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </term>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<item>
  See also<list rend="runon">
    <item>
      <term>Emotion</term>
    </item>
    <item>
      <term>Interpersonal conflict</term>
    </item>
  </list>
</item>
```

When run on an input file with just one `a.term-ref`, this produces:

```
<item>
  See also<item>
    <term>Interpersonal conflict</term>
  </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Sorry I did not clarify better, but I want <list rend="runon"> regardless of the number of items within it.